# What advantage does DbUnit bring to unit testing with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, oop, phpunit, dbunit

I'm thinking of using [DbUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/dbunit) with [PHPUnit](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit) to support my database testing. What are the benefits of using DbUnit?

My current way of doing things is manually setting up the fixture, making a change and then doing a comparison. Note no use of DbUnit:

```
public function testSomething() {
    // Create the fixture.
    $u1 = $this->user->create();
    $u2 = $this->user->create();

    // Modify the fixture.
    foo( $u1, $u2, true );

    // Perform a comparison.
    $this->assertEquals( 'some_value', MyClass::myMethod( $u1, $u2 ) );
}
```